# How to use explode mysql function in where condition with cakephp

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I am using cakephp 2.6. I have `payment_method` fields in mysql table which store the values like `54,52,59,57` .

Now my question is that how can i check if new posted payment method id is available in  the `payment_method` value.

Here `$data['PaymentMaster']['payment_method'] = 52`

```
$paymentDetail = $this->PaymentMaster->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('NOT' => array('payment_method'=>$data['PaymentMaster']['payment_method']))));
```

I want to check if value not in database then add in to database other wise fire an error that `Error: The rule is contradicting with the other rule, please check the rule.`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

by `Unique` constraint on your `payment_method` field, you can make sure that payment_method is unique. If the `peyment_method` is already exists, it will throw a SQL Error.

> Duplicate entry 'x' for key 'peyment_method'

The SQL for that would be:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName ADD UNIQUE (payment_method)
```

But if you mean you need to make sure this `payment_method` exists and the `payment_method_id` is in another table, you need foreign key.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD FOREIGN KEY `methodidCheck`(payment_method)
REFERENCES payment_method_table(payment_method_id);
```

Hope I got your question right